# Playing Multiple Videos on iPAD

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am facing some problem in playing multiple videos on iPAD. I am trying to play multiple thumbnail videos on the same view. You can say its much like the CCTV camera.Well, i have no clue. Please help me. Thanks in advance...

Comment: MPMoviePlayer controller will allow multiple instances, but only one of them can be playing their movie at any given time.

Comment: If this were for CCTV it seems that polling for a still image of each camera at a set frequency would be reasonable. Then the user could touch a camera to see the live video for that one. Otherwise it sounds like you are going to need to implement your own video player.

Comment: A different approach is to use AVAssetReader to read from two movie files. You can then push the data into OpenGL and render two video textures. You might be able to create a video composition with both sources and feed this to a single MPMoviePlayer.

Comment: Can i get any support from iPad 2(1 GHz dual core processore). Or completely goes with iOS restriction.

Comment: @Steve McFarlin
could you please refer me some sample...it'll be so nice of ya...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MPMoviePlayerController will allow multiple instances, but only one of them can be playing their movie at any given time.

It mentions it here:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html

From the article:

Note: Although you may create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time may play its movie.

Comment: Thanks...but could it be possible to do that thorough multiple threading?

Comment: No, i don't think so.  Even if it were possible, it would likely break apple's policies, and therefore not allow your app to get in the app store.

Comment: What might be an option is to have it alternatively start and stop each view so that it cycles through them.

Comment: you are saying that give the control to each instance in cyclic order. But will it be feasible? Because there are multiples views and except one all will be in stop state. But i need all of'em in running state in the same time.

Comment: What you want will not work.  You can't have them all playing at the same time.  What I was suggesting is that if what you are trying to do is like a view of security cameras, you could cycle through playing each "camera" one by one.  turn one on, play for a little while, turn one off, turn two off, etc. etc.

Comment: Okay...that's a probable solution.But I need to be sure about the solution so give some time to accept it. 

Thanks buddy for yar time...

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the MKMediaFramework to play multiple videos. You can however do this with the lower level AVFoundation Framework. It's not as hard as you might think and I've made a tutorial that goes over it here: http://www.sdkboy.com/?p=66

Essentially what you need to do is extend  UIView so it contains an AVPlayerLayer to which the output of an AVPlayer object is directed, then you can create multiple instances of this UIView that you feed video using AVPlayer instances.

Comment: seen your tutorial..pretty smart..but will apple accept this for app store

Comment: Hi Krishnabhadra , it shouldn't be a problem as you're not breaking any of Apple's rules. There are several apps already on the app store for VJing that play multiple videos. If the nature of your app requires the need for multiple videos and it's stable, then there shouldn't be any problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty simple to do on the iPad.

You basically need multiple `MPMoviePlayerController` objects.

Each `MPMoviePlayerController` object has a `view` property, you just need to set the frames of the `views` on the different `MPMoviePlayerController` objects to match what you want it to look like.

Here is a simple example using two `MPMoviePlayerController` objects ans 2 different `frames`:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player =
        [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
[[player view] setFrame: yourFrame1];
[myView addSubview: [player view]];
// ...
[player play];

MPMoviePlayerController *player2 =
            [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL2];
[[player2 view] setFrame: yourFrame2];
[myView addSubview: [player2 view]];
// ...
[player2 play];
```

Comment: Thanks...but as Stefan said only one of the instance get the control. here last instance(player2) is active.

Comment: @makboney: I have confirmed this is the case, and there doen't seem to be a way around it that doesn't mess with apple's policies. It is important to note that this limitation was based on the hardware; so with the new dual-core iPad this might change.

Answer (score -1):

May be When Creating a WebView and using a HTML5 Video instance you can run multiple videos at  the same time