# more than one MPMoviePlayer in a view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayer

I need to display more than one movieplayer in a view.

I know I can only play one video.

My problem is that only one of the two MPMovieplayer, I have added to the view, shows me the control buttons.

What can I do to solve my problem?

I use this code to add a movieplayer:

```
MPMoviePlayerController * moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(playerPlaybackDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(playerDidEnterFullscreen:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(playerDidExitFullscreen:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification
                                                object:moviePlayer];

    moviePlayer.view.frame = rect;

    [movie setContentURL:contentURL];
    [movie prepareToPlay];

    [self addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
```

Comment: Does it show the buttons if you touch it?

Answer (score 1):

I think its not possible. Please see the answer for this question
[Playing Multiple Videos on iPAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208900/playing-multiple-videos-on-ipad)

You will have to use AVPlayer for multiple video viewing, [see this](http://www.sdkboy.com/?p=66) 
Here is another [tutorial for AVPlayer](http://iosguy.com/2012/01/11/multiple-video-playback-on-ios/) 
You can also check this from apple developer portal, [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW20)

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258573/playing-many-different-videos-on-iphone-using-avplayer) also says something about adding controls to AVPlayer

BR,  Hari

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers, but I don't need to play more than one video. I only want to display more MPMovieplayers in a view. It must be possible to play only one video. Let's say for example there are two players (Player A and Player B). If a video is playing in Player A and you hit the play button in Player B, the movie in Player A should stop and Player B should play a video. I hope you understand that^^

Answer (score 0):

**Hi this is not possible to play more than 1 video in ios because only one thread at a time .**

I face same issue in my iPad application but I've found an alternate solution.

I want to play more video in 1 view controller , but these videos are 4 to 5 sec's only.

I make number of continuous image frames of that video's and make .gif  files and show this in a UIWebView. it works fine.