# how to show multi videos on single view in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, video-streaming, mpmovieplayer

i tried following-

created different instances of `MPMoviePlayer` on a single view but at a time only one video is playing. i am not getting how to do this. I have to do this for live camera video streaming on single view  that is 4 camera output on single view. just give me the idea or way.

Comment: `MPMoviePlayerController` does not support the playback of multiple videos concurrently (as noted within the docs). You will have to use `AVPlayer` to get that done (which supports such scenario).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in apple documentation you can not do this using MPMoviePlayerController.

```
Although you can create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and present their
views in your interface, only one movie player at a time can play its movie.
```

So checkout this nice tutorial for [multiple-video-playback-on-ios](http://iosguy.com/2012/01/11/multiple-video-playback-on-ios/).

and check this nice [sample code](http://www.sdkboy.com/?p=66) also.

So finally you can use [AVPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayer) for this because you can have multiple instances of `AVPlayer` playing the same video at the same time. .

Answer (score 0):

MPMovieplayer can play only a single video at a time.Concurrancy support you have to look more on AVPlayer.I saw one [example of it in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208900/playing-multiple-videos-on-ipad) itself .